# Declare a variable to store an object that is only constructed with a specific named constructor in dart

Tags: flutter, variables, dart, constructor

```
    class ExampleClass {
      //default constructor
      ExampleClass() {
        //do stuff
      }
      //named constructor
      ExampleClass.namedConstructor() {
        //do stuff
      }
    }
    void main() {
     //is there a way to create a variable with datatype to store an object that is constructed only with a specific constructor?

//I have tried something like this, but it returns an error
         ExampleClass.namedConstructor variable_1;
    }
```

Is there any way to do this or an alternative? because I need to be able to differentiate between an object that is constructed with the default constructor or with a named constructor.

Comment: Could you say for what use case you need to have such thing? Just to see if the things I have in my mind may help your use case.

Comment: Okay ,what im trying to do is to use this one class for multiple purpose and for the class to be multi purpose i need the class to be constructed via different constructor,when i declared a variable to store this object i just realized that there are no way to differentiate if this or that object in the variable is constructed with a specific constructor, im sorry if im not clear with my explanation

Comment: You can extend class to other class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some identification to classes builded with different constructors and compare entities by unique parameters.

If instances of your classes creating once (Singleton design pattern), you can create entities as constants and compare it by reference:

```dart
const administrator = User.administrator();

class User {
  final int id;

  User(this.id);

  factory User.administrator() {
    return User(0);
  }

  factory User.administrator(int id) {
    return User(id);
  }
}
```